# OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant without secret

Tags: azure, oauth, adal

So I've been looking at setting up OAuth 2.0 for a Cordova mobile app using Microsofts [cordova-plugin-ms-adal plugin](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) (which uses the native libs) against a custom API using Azure AD. This all works well but I'm a bit confused with the use of the secret (or more specifically its absence).

In many articles on the web they state that when using the Authorization Code Grant and requesting a token, you include the secret. And that this grant type is ideal for use when you can securely store the secret e.g. on a server.

However the plugin **does not require that a secret is specified in the app** (and rightly so) but it still uses the Authorization Code Grant to authenticate. Also I can manually call

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=http://***.onmicrosoft.com/***API&client_id=***&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://***.onmicrosoft.com/***App
```

in my browser, login, get the code and then POST to https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token with

```
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: ***
code: ***
redirect_uri: http://***.onmicrosoft.com/***App
resource: http://***.onmicrosoft.com/***API
```

and it works, so I get back a valid JWT, **without having to send a secret**.

Why!? Is this less secure? (I also noticed that the [OAuth 2.0 spec section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) does not state that the secret is required for grant type Authorization Code!?)

**What are the implications of using a grant type of authorization_code without a secret / basic auth header?**

Comment: Can you tell me how did you get the code in the browser login and did you make a POST using Javascript or any server side Language.

I am facing this issue and need your help!!!!

Comment: @SouravDas So that I could get a better understanding I was calling the endpoints manually. Once you call the first URL in your browser and login it redirects to the redirect_uri you have configured with a ?code= param. Use this value when you POST to the token endpoint - I used https://www.getpostman.com for testing this. In my actual code I have the cordova-plugin-ms-adal plugin setup which handles this for me!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We use ADFS not AZAD so, i guess i have to write the whole thing!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implication of using `grant_type=authorization_code` (or any other flow) with a public client (one that does not have a secret or authenticate in any other way) is that the access token granted does not represent an authorization of the client (the app) to *directly* access the resource, it represents an authorization for the client to access the resource *on behalf of the user*.

This is why you'll notice in <strike>Azure AD</strike> Entra ID that when you register a native client app (a public client) you can only configure it to have delegated permissions to a resource, and not app-only permissions.

Answer (score 13):

Using the Authorization Code grant with a so-called confidential client (a client that has a client secret) is more secure than using a public Client indeed.

That is because the exchange of the authorization code itself happens as URL parameter in the front-channel i.e. through the browser and as such is relatively vulnerable to attacks like cross-scripting, click-jacking, network/DNS manipulation etc. That means that it is possible for a dedicated attacker to steal the authorization code from a user in certain circumstances (sloppy user, attacker network control, sloppy redirect URI matching in the server implementation, etc.).

To exchange the authorization code for an Access Token, a confidential Client would have to present the client secret on an HTTPs protected call alongside of the authorization code, whereas a public Client doesn't have any means of making sure that it is really the designated Client.

This means that it is *relatively* easy for an attacker to mimic a public Client since that requires only non-secret information (he can grab the `client_id` and the `redirect_uri` from his own browser) and the authorization `code` that he can grab through an attack as described above.

Though grabbing the authorization code for a confidential Client works in the same way, the attacker cannot use it and exchange it for an Access Token because in order to do so he needs a client secret which is typically much harder to obtain for the attacker. The secret is usually stored on the server in backend storage and communicated only over a secure HTTPs channel so it doesn't leak.

Answer (score 1):

> without having to send a secret.

Not true. In the [link you posted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) the request includes also:

`Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW`

Maybe you didn't notice it. This shows the `client_secret`  being transmitted in an encoded form, using HTTP Basic Authentication.

It's up to the server to decide how the client authenticates (if necessary). From the specification :

> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client
> credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the
> client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described
> in Section 3.2.1.

Sec 3.2.1 directs to section 2.3 (seriously), which says:

> Clients in possession of a client password MAY use the HTTP Basic
> authentication scheme as defined in [RFC2617] to authenticate with
> the authorization server.

client password is aka client secret.

So the secret is being transmitted.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I'll admit that I didn't notice that in the spec example! I guess my question is: what are the implications of using a grant type of authorization_code without a secret / basic auth header? (I've updated my question to reflect this.)